# sql runner pge?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

does anyone know what the c# looks like or can point me to the sample online of a page that consits of a textbox that you can type a sql command into, a button and a bound grid that will be bound the the sql that was entered.

Comment: Seriously? whats next, a button to bring world peace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very big no no (because anybody with access to the page can do anything to your database) but If I understand you correctly, the following will work:

In your button_click method that gets called when you click the button you can do the following:

```
DataSet dsResults = new DataSet();
string connectionString = "Data Source=[Server]; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=[DataBaseName];"
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(txtSql.Text,sqlCon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
        da.Fill(dsResults);
    }

    gvResults.DataSource = dsResults;
    gvResults.DataBind();
```

where gvResults is your datagrid and txtSql is your textbox you enter the sql into.
Also remember to set your connection string in the variable named connection string

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) which is a pretty much exactly what you describe, just with lots of extra bells and whistles.

Its open source and the source code can be found [here on Google code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/)